# Cordova installation issues

Tags: android, cordova

[I have followed all the procedure which is mentioned in cordova tutorial point, i'm stuck in building the app for the specified platform where we can run it on mobile device or emulator, it showing failed to run javac -version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4lx0.png)

Comment: this is not the cordova or java support forum

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that come in mind is that you don't have the jre/jdk installed

Comment: i have jdk & jre installed , path is set properly. even android studio runs well. when i execute "javac -version " in cmd, version gets displayed. i m not able to figure out the issue